# How can I download Mobilecore SDK for Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, sdk, ads

I am developing a game now and I have to integrate MobileCore Ads in my project.
But I can`t know where and how can I download this SDK for Unity.
I logged in mobilecore site and searched unity SDK in Dashboard/Resources.
But I could see only Android and iOS SDKs.
There was no unity plugin.
I tried to get this, but had nothing now.
Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to add it as a [plugin](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Plugins.html). You can find it [here](https://dashboard.mobilecore.com/#resources/android/framework-plugins/8) with details on how to install it. Download the plugin and unpack into your Assets -> Plugins -> Android folder of your project. Initialize the plugin with

```
public MobilecoreAndroid (string devHash, int logType, GameObject gameObject, params string[] adUnits)
```